# Are air traffic controllers required to obtain a pilot license?

Tags: air-traffic-control, flight-training

Here in my home country (Hong Kong), all air traffic controllers are required  to obtain a PPL as part of their training. The reason being, if the controllers can better imagine a pilot's perspective, they can better accommodate and provide assistance to pilots. I don't think they are required to keep the license current, but sure they need to pass all PPL exams.

Is this requirement common around the world? (Note that I intentionally do not specify which country or jurisdiction. I'm looking for an answer which lists the countries which have this requirement.)

Comment: No requirement in the UK and I'm sorry, I am going to vote to close since this question could have 178 answers of "not in xxx country".  Perhaps you could reword it to say please only answer or comment if the answer is "yes".

Comment: @Simon instead of 178 answers, perhaps an answer would say "Except for Country A, B & C, the US, Australia and all other European countries do not have this".

Comment: @kevin I'm not trying to be confrontational, but I can't actually find any 'evidence' that Honk Kong air traffic controllers obtain (or are required to) a Private Pilots License as part of their training. Can you cite some references for that as it does appear to be a very unusual requirement and well beyond ICAO

Comment: Interesting, I can indeed find quite a few references to flying training as part of becoming a controller (Though I can't confirm whether they have to graduate as a pilot). It's an interesting one - I can certainly understand "seeing the other side", but I question how much of a crossover between having a good aptitude for flying vs being a good controller there really is. (NB: I'm sure many do both extremely well, I'm just not convinced that there's a real correlation)

Comment: @Dan http://www.cad.gov.hk/english/atm_training.html . Training takes around a year, during which 3 months are spent overseas to obtain a PPL, usually Australia or New Zealand.

Comment: @kevin Thanks Kevin - I don't want to go too far off the point of your question, but it has sparked my interest. It's this line I can't quite fathom - ' "As part of the air traffic control training, SATCO have the opportunity to take up overseas flying training in single-engine light aircraft." which doesn't imply it's a mandatory requirement, but that might be just the wording.

Comment: In the US, controllers are required to do *some* ground and flight training (at least in some training tracks), but there is no requirement to complete that training by earning a pilot certificate.

Comment: I find it unbelievable that controllers in China have pilot's license. It very difficult and expensive to fly in China and they have a severe shortage of pilots. Until 2013 it was extremely difficult to even fly at all because of the need to obtain permissions weeks in advance for each and every flight. If a controller had a license, why would he even work as a controller when he could make much more money as a pilot? The statement in the question just isn't believable.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such requirement here in Germany.